Using Kotlin and AWS SDK, copy file without file without triggering AWS S3 event
Using Kotlin and AWS SDK, how to copy a file in a s3 bucket without triggering the event notification? or not triggering the lambdas connected to the event notification?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketNotificationConfiguration.html
says, "You can disable notifications by adding the empty NotificationConfiguration element.
"
Also, the Python AWS SDK link https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_bucket_notification_configuration.html
says,
"By default, your bucket has no event notifications configured. That is, the notification configuration will be an empty NotificationConfiguration.
This action replaces the existing notification configuration with the configuration you include in the request body."
Few things, I am trying to process files.  This process involves a copy of these files.  But, there are event notifications on the S3 bucket that are needed for daily use.  So looking for a way to do the processing without triggering the event notifications, if possible.
Also, side note: the AWS documentation keeps referring to "adding the empty NotificationConfiguration element".  Using Kotlin, how would I make an "empty" NotificationConfiguration?  When I set the NotificationConfiguration to null, I get a exception about it being null.  So not really sure what is meant by "empty".
